# Mean matrix of matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab

i'm new to matlab and I'd like to ask something.
Is there any function in matlab that allow me to make mean matrix of matrices?

To give you some picture, for example I have matrices like this :

```
A = [ 1 2
      3 4 ]

B = [ 3 2 
      1 2 ]
```

and then what I want for the mean matrix that I meant earlier is like this

```
Mean = [ 2 2
         2 3 ]
```

Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it simply like the following:

```
a = [1 2 ;...
     3 4];

b = [1 3 ;...
     1 2];

sum = a + b;

mean = sum ./ 2;
```

And it will be:

```
mean =

    1.0000    2.5000
    2.0000    3.0000
```

Answer (score 5):

another option:

```
 mean([A(:) B(:)]')

 ans =

        2     2     2     3
```

This will make a vector from the two matrices and return a vector of the mean you wanted, you can then reshape it back to 2x2 using `reshape`,

```
reshape(mean([A(:) B(:)]'),size(A))

ans =

     2     2
     2     3
```

**Edit:** Eitan suggested the following one-liner solution that is more efficient:

```
mean(cat(ndims(A) + 1, A, B), ndims(A) + 1)
```

Comment: I think `mean(cat(3, A, B), 3)` is better, and it doesn't require reshaping.

Comment: +1 your suggestion is some 20%-25% faster (in my machine), but my one liner can deal with matrices with any dimension...

Comment: You can always concatenate the matrices in the next "vacant" dimension, so my solution handles any dimension as well: `mean(cat(ndims(A) + 1, A, B), ndims(A) + 1)`

Comment: Well done Eitan, that's a much better one liner than the one I suggested (and I've learned about `ndims` too)...

Comment: feel free to incorporate it in your solution :)